# how to install a software only on a server and run a separated instance of that software on every computer connected to that server?

Tags: networking, application-server

I'm using an IBM Servers running windows server 2008 R2 and windows server 2012

I tried learning about application servers like IBM Web sphere but I need some guidance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.